# Problem loading an "interval" from a CSV file

Tags: postgresql, bulk-load

I am trying to create a table using a csv file that is very big. Amongst the data, I have a column named 'bouwjaar' which means construction year and I have selected 'date' as a date type. I would receive an error, therefore I changed the date type into an interval but it again won't work. It gives me the following error. What should I select as a date type?

> ERROR:  interval field value out of range: "1971-1980"
> CONTEXT:  COPY fundadata, line 24, column bouwjaar : "1971-1980"

Comment: you should make this a string - it will not parse as a single date

Answer (score 2):

An `interval` in PostgreSQL is not something with a starting point and and end point, but a duration like "9 years".

A more appropriate data type for that would be `daterange`, but the values would have to look like `[1971-01-01,1981-01-01)`. You either have to pre-process the file before loading, or you have to load the data into a `text` column and post-process it.

Comment: or possibly `int4range` with data format `"(1971,1981)"` in the CSV file